# C++ with Mono Embedded (C#), Sending Pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, mono, embedded

is it possible to send pointers (void**) to c# via Mono Embedded and receiving pointers later on?
How could it be done?

Thank you.

Comment: any news on this? I need to pass a pointer of a c++ struct into c#, in order to marshal the structure into my C# datatype

Answer (score 0):

You can use pointers in c# by marking your code as unsafe, such as:

```
unsafe void* my_method(void* myparam) { return myparam; }
```

or:

```
unsafe
{
    void* pvt_void;

    void* get_member() { return pvt_void; }
}
```